# Excel: 1.auto search duplicate rows > 2.combine columns > 3.remove duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying numerous combinations for hours but I couldn't find a solution. I have an excel file with 20k data and this is what I'm trying to do:

```
 ItemOEM     BrandTxt
 51604A     ThinkJet
 51604A     QuietJet
 51605R     ThinkJet
 51605R     QuietJet
```

to:

```
 ItemOEM     BrandTxt
 51604A      ThinkJet,QuietJet
 51605R      ThinkJet,QuietJet
```

For my entire excel file with thousands of rows. Is it possible? If it is, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is possible with VBA. Are you open to such course?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you cannot do this with Excel formulae alone, so you'll probably need to resort to VBA Macros to achieve this. And I have to say, honestly, that I hate VBA and would instead export the data in a CSV format and write an external script to do this, then re-import the final CSV once the desired changes are made.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel-VBA tag was added to your question as VBA will be required to automate this process to any level of success.

```
Sub concat_dedupe()
    Dim rw As Long, fnd As Range
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        With .Columns(1)
            For rw = 2 To .Rows.Count
                If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells.Offset(rw, 0), .Cells(rw, 1).Value)) Then
                    If Not CBool(Application.CountIf(.Cells.Resize(rw - 1), .Cells(rw, 1).Value)) Then
                        Set fnd = .Find(What:=.Cells(rw, 1).Value, After:=.Cells(rw, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                        Do While fnd.Address <> .Cells(rw, 1).Address
                            .Cells(rw, 1).Offset(0, 1) = .Cells(rw, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value & "," & fnd.Offset(0, 1).Value
                            Set fnd = .FindNext(fnd)
                        Loop
                    End If
                End If
            Next rw
        End With
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Your problem interested me in that the subsequent removal of duplicates after the string concatenation will actually reduce the number of necessary string concatenations as only the first instance of any *ItemOEM* will retain it. Whether this increases efficiency would be a factor of how many string concats there are; e.g. does checking for previous operations on that *ItemOEM* save processing cycles over the long run. This will depend upon how many duplications there are but I think it is the better way to go.